# Show context menu on-click (marker)

Tags: google-maps, contextmenu

I have this code for **context menu** and it's working fine

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(e)
{
    // start buy hiding the context menu if its open
    contextMenu.hide();

    var mapDiv = $(map.getDiv()),
        x = e.pixel.x,
        y = e.pixel.y;

    // save the clicked location
    clickedLatLng = e.latLng;

    // adjust if clicked to close to the edge of the map
    if ( x > mapDiv.width() - contextMenu.width() )
        x -= contextMenu.width();

    if ( y > mapDiv.height() - contextMenu.height() )
        y -= contextMenu.height();

    // Set the location and fade in the context menu
    contextMenu.css({ top: y, left: x }).fadeIn(100);
});
```

My question is why this isn't working, the same thing but click is now **startMarker** **click**?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(startMarker, 'click', function(e) {
            // start buy hiding the context menu if its open
            contextMenu.hide();

            var mapDiv = $(map.getDiv()),
                x = e.pixel.x,
                y = e.pixel.y;

            // save the clicked location
            clickedLatLng = e.latLng;

            // adjust if clicked to close to the edge of the map
            if ( x > mapDiv.width() - contextMenu.width() )
                x -= contextMenu.width();

            if ( y > mapDiv.height() - contextMenu.height() )
                y -= contextMenu.height();

            // Set the location and fade in the context menu
            contextMenu.css({ top: y, left: x }).fadeIn(100);
          });
```

And the rest of the code

```
// Create the context menu element
var contextMenu = $(document.createElement('ul')).attr('id', 'contextMenu');

// Fill our context menu with links
contextMenu.append(
    '<li><a href=\"#startMenu\">Start</a></li>' +
    '<li><a href=\"#stopMenu\">End</a></li>'
);

// Disable the browser context menu on our context menu
contextMenu.bind('contextmenu', function() { return false; });

// Append it to the map object
$(map.getDiv()).append(contextMenu);


// Set some events on the context menu links
contextMenu.find('a').click( function()
{
    // fade out the menu
    contextMenu.fadeOut(75);

    // The link's href minus the #
    var action = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);

    switch (action) {
        case 'startMenu':
            $.get('something1.php', method1);
            break;

        case 'stopMenu':
            $.get('something2.php', method2);   
            break;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got to activate the context menu right click on the map and mark, steps:

1) Create a new MapCanvasProjection to use fromLatLngToContainerPixel function:

```
overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay.draw = function() {};
overlay.setMap(map);
```

2) For Each Marker include RightClick Listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function() {

    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'rightclick', this);

});
```

3) Replace the RightClick Listener Map with:

```
g.event.addListener(this.theMap, 'rightclick', function(e)
{

            try { 

            var lpx =     overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel(e.getPosition());
            var latLng_r=e.getPosition();

            } catch(err) { 

            var lpx=e.pixel;
            var latLng_r=e.latLng;

        }

        // Shorthand some stuff
        var mapDiv = $(self.theMap.getDiv()),
               menu = self.theMenu,
                       x = lpx.x,
               y = lpx.y;

        // Hide the context menu if its open
        menu.hide();

        // Save the clicked location
            self.clickedLatLng = latLng_r;

        // Adjust the menu if clicked to close to the edge of the map
        if ( x > mapDiv.width() - menu.width() )
            x -= menu.width();

            if ( y > mapDiv.height() - menu.height() )
            y -= menu.height();

        // Set the location and fade in the context menu
                menu.css({ top: y, left: x }).fadeIn(200);
        });

        // Hide context menu on several events
        $.each('click dragstart zoom_changed maptypeid_changed center_changed'.split(' '), function(i,name){
            g.event.addListener(self.theMap, name, function(){ self.theMenu.hide(); });
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Marker event (e) does not return a pixel object or a latLng object (unlike a map event) - it only returns x & y coordinates of the event - so the following lines in your code will not work for the marker

```
 x = e.pixel.x,
 y = e.pixel.y;
clickedLatLng = e.latLng;
```

To get coordinates you will need to replace the lines above with

```
x=e.x
y=e.y
```

You will not be able to get latLng object from clicking on the marker. I suppose best way to get that is to read the object from the property of the marker itself.

```
clickedLatLng  = startMarker.getPosition()
```

Comment: but I'm getting real x,y coordinates - I need those in pixels - should I use fromLatLngToContainerPixel with OverelayView or...?